# MySQL - Trigger to update a column value based on update other table column value

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update, database-trigger

I need to update TABLE_B on column 'paid' in an specific ID everytime TABLE_A gets updated on the column 'paid' for that same ID either.

I'm trying to think on some solution using triggers, but can't discover how.

Comment: This sounds like redundancy/poor design

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want something like:

```
delimiter //

create trigger mytrigger
after update on table_a
for each row
begin
    if not (new.paid <=> old.paid) then
        update table_b set paid = new.paid where id = new.id;
    end if;
end;
//

delimiter ;
```

The trigger fires after each `update` on `table_b`. The `if` condition checks if the value of column `paid` changed, and, if it did, it updates column `paid` in `table_b` to the same value on the row whose `id` matches the `id` of the updated row in `table_a`.

Comment: Exactly. I was doing something like this earlier and I think that this is correct. However, i keep getting the 'Error Code: 2013 Lost connection to MySQL server during query'.
 My Table_B has 35000 rows and my Table_A is uppdated 2000 times a day. 
Would this solution be unappropriated?

Comment: 2000 executions a day against a 35000 rows table shouldn't be a problem at all. You might consider an index on `id` on both tables to speed up the updates.